# UINavigationController Freezes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

So I have this very simple code.

```
//Push the uiviewcontroller of the juice
JuiceViewController *viewController = [[JuiceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JuiceViewController" bundle:nil];
//Set the object tot os displaying
viewController.mProductRef=juice;
//Push the view controller
[navController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

It works 90% of the time, the other 10% the screen freezes, but the app does not crash. The navigation did happen its just the animation that freezes.

I know this because if I do the side swipe to go back the screen pop back in to the correct form.

Like I said 90% of the time it does what I expect but sometimes it freezes.

I have never seen this before in any of my project. Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Comment: I know this sounds weird, but is the background color of the UIView associated with the JuiceViewController instantiated? If you haven't tried specifying a background color, try that.

Comment: @AlexKoren Yeah, I did that yesterday but the problem continued. However I analyzed my code and noticed that I was missing [super viewWillAppear] on the viewcontrollers I was pushing. So I added them. The problem hasn't shown up since. I don't want to say for sure that was the problem, but its worth trying if anyone else runs into this problem.

Comment: My app freezes randomly if I do any UIView animation or push action. But view goes right after resign and reactive application.